# Searching issue using lucene.Net

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to your the search engine of Lucene .Net. i followed some documentation on the website but i might have missed something since it doesn't work as expected ..

Here is the code :

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"c:\Test\testRoot.pdf");
        for (var page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page) + " ");
        }
        if (stringBuilder.ToString().Contains("new"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New is present in the text!");
        }
        const string strIndexDir = @"C:\Index";
        Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.Open(strIndexDir);
        Analyzer std = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        var idwx = new IndexWriter(indexDir, std, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        var doc = new Document();            
        var fdl = new Field("testRoot", stringBuilder.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        doc.Add(fdl);
        idwx.AddDocument(doc);
        idwx.Optimize();
        idwx.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Indexing Done !");


        var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "new", std);
        var qry = parser.Parse(parser.Field);
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir));
        Searcher srch = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(directory, true));
        TopScoreDocCollector cllstr = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = cllstr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            int docId = hits[i].Doc;
            float score = hits[i].Score;
            Document docy = srch.Doc(docId);
            Console.WriteLine(docy.Get("text"));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The thing is That the word new is present in the text of my PDF since it goes in the 'if'.

but at the end, when i try to look for the match, nothing's here ..

EDIT:

i made few changes but still doesn't work:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"c:\Test\testRoot.pdf");
        for (var page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page) + " ");
        }
        if (stringBuilder.ToString().Contains("new"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New is present in the text!");
        }
        const string strIndexDir = @"C:\Index";
        Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.Open(strIndexDir);
        Analyzer std = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
        var idwx = new IndexWriter(indexDir, std, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        var doc = new Document();            
        var fdl = new Field("testRoot", stringBuilder.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        doc.Add(fdl);
        idwx.AddDocument(doc);
        idwx.Optimize();
        idwx.Commit();
        idwx.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("Indexing Done !");
        var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "", std);
        var qry = parser.Parse("new*");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir));
        Searcher srch = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(directory, true));
        var lol = srch.Search(qry, 100);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = lol.ScoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            int docId = hits[i].Doc;
            float score = hits[i].Score;
            Document docy = srch.Doc(docId);
            Console.WriteLine(docy.Get("testRoot"));
        }
```

Thanks you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "testRoot", std);
```

Or:

```
var qry = parser.Parse("testRoot:new*");
```

You need to specify the correct field to search in.  It appears the `testRoot` is the field name you are looking for.  The second argument to `QueryParser` specifies the default field to search.  In the first example shown you provided, you call it "new", which doesn't appear to be the name of a field being added to your document (essentially, in that case, your query looks like: `new:new`).  This default field will be used for searching unless you specify the field to search in your query, such as `myField:findThis` (see the [query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields)).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this was the problem ;)